# Automatically including the foreign key within the second form

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am trying make the use primary key in the ReviewComments model to link with the foreign key in the ReviewPhoto model within the same webpage.

Model.py

```
class ReviewComments(models.Model):
    comment_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    receipt_document = models.FileField(upload_to='receipt_document', default=None, )
    service_provider = models.ForeignKey(ServiceProvider)
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True, )

class ReviewPhoto(models.Model):
    photo_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    photo_description = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='review_photo', default=None)
    review_comments = models.ForeignKey(ReviewComments)
```

Views.py

```
def form_review_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form_1 = ReviewForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form_2 = PhotoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form_1.is_valid() and form_2.is_valid():
            form_1.save()
            form_2.save()
            return redirect('index_view')
        else:
            return render_to_response(
                'form_review.html',
                {'form_1': form_1, 'form_2': form_2},
                context_instance=RequestContext(request),
            )
    else:
        form_1 = ReviewForm()
        form_2 = PhotoForm()
        return render_to_response(
            'form_review.html',
            {'form_1': form_1, 'form_2': form_2},
            context_instance=RequestContext(request),
        )
```

Forms.py

```
class ReviewForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ReviewComments
        fields = ['title', 'comment', 'service_provider', 'receipt_document', ]
        widgets = {
        'title': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 1}),
        'comment': Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80, 'rows': 10}),
        }
        ordering = ['service_provider', ]


class PhotoForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = ReviewPhoto
        fields = ['photo_description', 'photo', ]
```

However, I am not able to get the forms to post the required data as the "review_comment" field in ReviewPhoto is not automatically picking up the "comment_id" field in ReviewComments. Is there any way around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have posted your form. But I think this is what you want:

```
if form_1.is_valid() and form_2.is_valid():
    review = form_1.save()
    photo = form_2.save(commit=False)
    photo.review_comments = review
    photo.save()
```

Also consider using more descriptive names than `form_1` and `form_2`.